# Getting the direct link to image stored in Sharepoint Library on external site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a company public website that is using some images from our Sharepoint internal site. I have an API that is getting the content from the list as well as the direct image url that goes in the website. The problem is that when I'm not logged in in Sharepoint in the browser, the images are not loading. Sharing a link from the document library does nothing as the user needs to go on that link first to authenticate and then the access is allowed. Is there any way that I can do this and I'm not considering other cloud storage options for my images, it must be from Sharepoint.